# Cannot find method getActiveCell(string)

Tags: google-sheets, syntax-error

I am trying to select a sheet name from a drop down validation list and then click on an image to jump to that sheet. I used the script below but it gives me an error

> "Cannot find method getActiveCell(string)."

```
function showSheetByName(Name) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(ss.getActiveCell('R5').getValue());
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet();
};
```

R5 in the script above represents the drop down validating cell where I can select the name of different sheets.

Comment: What kind of spreadsheet/language are you actually using? Cheers!

Comment: I got this from this online forum. This is a google sheet script.

Comment: Did the below answer do what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Google Spreadsheets before but the concept is similar to Excel VBA (which I have), so I've taken a stab and your problem is that `getActiveCell()` does not take a cell reference; it purely gets the cell that is active, you can't change the cell that is active with it. So to use your code you'd first need to make R5 the active cell. I found the function `setActiveSelection` which will do this. Example of working code below:

```
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  currentSheet.setActiveSelection("R5")
  var newSheetName = currentSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(newSheetName));
```

You can find more details on the methods [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), you might want to look at the method `getRange` as well, I suspect with that you could get the value of 'R5' without having to first make the cell active.

Comment: d219, You're a genius !!! It worked!! I had to make one small correction but it was like magic! Thank you for your help and support!.

Comment: No worries, if you could mark this as an accepted answer then that'd be great - encourages people to keep helping :)